# Svelte doesn't rerender when value of variable changes

Tags: javascript, svelte

Hello i have a problem with my login page, when a user logs in i want to check whether they did it with otp or password if with otp the page should change and show a new modal that prompts the user to set a new password, but it seems like the value of the set_new_password variable doesn't change and svelte doesn't rerender the component.

here is the login function and variables.

```
let inpEmail;
let inpPassword;
let set_new_password = false;


  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("${API}/api/get_token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: inpEmail,
            password: inpPassword,
        }),
    })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                console.log("login failed");
                throw new Error("login failed");
            }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.message == "otp_used") {
                console.log("otp_used");
                set_new_password = true;
                console.log(set_new_password)
                infoToast("OTP used, please set a password");
                return;
            }
            localStorage.setItem("auth", data.token);
            getUserData(token);
            navigate("/");
        });
};
```

and here is my html

```
{#if !set_new_password}
    <Card class="flex justify-center items-center p-16">
        <div class="container">
            <h1
                class="text-2xl font-bold text-center mb-10 focus:outline-none focus:border-none"
            >
                Login
            </h1>
            <Input
                name="Email or Username"
                type="email"
                class="mb-5"
                bind:value={inpEmail}
            />
            <Input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                class="mb-10"
                bind:value={inpPassword}
            />
            <PrimaryButton class="float-right" on:click={handleLogin}
                >Login</PrimaryButton
            >
        </div>
    </Card>
{:else}
    <Card class="flex justify-center items-center p-16">
        <div class="container">
            <h1
                class="text-2xl font-bold text-center mb-10 focus:outline-none focus:border-none"
            >
                Change Password
            </h1>
            <Input
                name="Email or Username"
                type="text"
                class="mb-5"
                bind:value={inpEmail}
            />
            <Input
                name="One Time Password"
                type="text"
                class="mb-5"
                bind:value={otp}
            />
            <Input
                name="New Password"
                type="password"
                class="mb-5"
                bind:value={newPassword}
            />
            <Input
                name="Confirm Password"
                type="password"
                class="mb-10"
                bind:value={confirmPassword}
            />
            <PrimaryButton
                class="float-right"
                on:click={handle_new_password}>Set Password</PrimaryButton
            >
        </div>
    </Card>
{/if}
```

the console displays otp_used but the component doesn't rerender

Comment: You can log set_new_password like this $:console.log("set_new_password", set_new_password) and see if it is updating

Comment: It is not updating

Answer (score 0):

you're navigating somewhere else in here:

```
.then((data) => {
        console.log ('data',data);  //What does this output
        if (data.message == "otp_used") {
            console.log("otp_used");
            set_new_password = true;
            console.log(set_new_password)
            infoToast("OTP used, please set a password");
            return;
        }
        localStorage.setItem("auth", data.token);
        getUserData(token);
        navigate("/");   //<<- Try remove this?
    });
```

Perhaps the navigate function is changing your route so the modal is not showing.